# Chart.js bar charts not all the same width in Angular table

Tags: angular, chart.js

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gv9od4)

I have an application that displays a table of compliance counts for a number of rules. For each rule, a stacked bar chart (created with [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) and [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) is provided showing the percentage of compliant vs non-compliant rules. The charts aren't all the same width, and I'm not sure why. The application is written in Angular 16, using the Material component library. How can I get my graphs all the same width?